# Microsoft ASP.NET Dependency Injection container generic issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, generics, dependency-injection

I am using MediatR with pipelines and need to be sure that services are registered in proper order. So I register them this way:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(CommandLoggingBehavior<,>));
services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(PermissionBehavior<,>));
services.AddTransient<IPipelineBehavior<RegistrationCommand, Result<AuthorizationResponse>>, ValidationBehavior<RegistrationCommand, Result<AuthorizationResponse>>>();
services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(TransactionPipelineBehavior<,>));
services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(DistributedLockPipelineBehavior<,>));
```

All these implementations except for the ValidationBehavior are using generic constraints and should be registered for all generic arguments coming. ValidationBehavior is only registered for types that have a validator, so it needs to have exact generic arguments upon registering in a container.
So everything is okay when I get all services for the `IPipelineBehavior<RegistrationCommand, Result<AuthorizationResponse>>` type before the builder is built (I am not really using this, it is written for debugging purposes):

```
var provider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
var pipelines = provider.GetServices<IPipelineBehavior<RegistrationCommand, Result<AuthorizationResponse>>>();

var app = builder.Build();
```

Pipelines have all the 5 pipelines added in correct order and implementation.

But when this exact method for getting services is executed in application runtime this happens:
[image: Services during runtime]

The last behavior (that is DistributedLockPipelineBehavior) gets replaced by duplicate of ValidationBehavior for some reason.
If I try to add another DistributedLockPipelineBehavior in service registration like this

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(CommandLoggingBehavior<,>));
services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(PermissionBehavior<,>));
services.AddTransient<IPipelineBehavior<RegistrationCommand, Result<AuthorizationResponse>>, ValidationBehavior<RegistrationCommand, Result<AuthorizationResponse>>>();
services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(TransactionPipelineBehavior<,>));
services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(DistributedLockPipelineBehavior<,>));
services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(DistributedLockPipelineBehavior<,>));
```

Only the last one gets replaced:
[image: Only the last service gets replaced]

I don't understand what is happening here, what am I missing that breaks the service registration?

I created a new project, here's the code I've written in Program.cs. The issue is present: the last behavior is replaced:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(CommandLoggingBehavior<,>));
builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(PermissionBehavior<,>));
builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<MockRequest, MockResponse>), typeof(ValidationBehavior<MockRequest, MockResponse>));
builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(TransactionBehavior<,>));
builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(DistributedLockBehavior<,>));

var app = builder.Build();
var pipes = app.Services.GetServices<IPipelineBehavior<MockRequest, MockResponse>>();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();


public class MockRequest { }
public class MockResponse { }

public interface IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> { }

public class ValidationBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> { }

public class CommandLoggingBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> { }

public class PermissionBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> { }

public class TransactionBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> { }

public class DistributedLockBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> { }
```

I wrote adding the ValidationBehavior 2 more times, this is what I get:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried building a Minimal, Reproducible Example, for instance as a small console application. The behavior is so weird that I can't imagine this being a bug in MS.DI.

Comment: @Steven I have added an example that reproduces the issue

Comment: Fun fact: if you duplicate the adding of ValidationBehavior (or any other dependency with concrete types) all the other ones will be replaced. I duplicated adding ValidationBehavior 2 more times and I get 7 dependencies resolved - CommandLogging, Permission and 5 Validation behaviors

Comment: I tested your code example and was able to reproduce this. As you described: when you call `builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider.GetServices<IPipelineBehavior<MockRequest, MockResponse>>()` you do get the expected list of configured dependencies, but when resolved from `app.Services.GetServices<...>()` the list is incorrect. I do believe this to be a bug in the .NET framework, because it makes no sense at all that there is difference in behavior between the two calls. IMO it's a very, very scary bug. You should report this issue with Microsoft.

Comment: Tested this in both .NET 6 and .NET 7 and the bug exists in both versions.

Comment: David Fowler is mentioning on Twitter that this bug was likely fixed already in .NET 8. You might want to verify this, and if not, make sure to file a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Steven in the comments, this is a bug in the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection package.

See the discussion on the [dotnet GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/87017) and the discussion on the [MediatR GitHub](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/issues/884).

The issue is fixed, but the fix isn't on the stable branch yet. Once it has been stable in the v8.0 release (which is RC at the time of writing), it will be backported:

> Are there any requests to backport the fix to v7 and possible v6
> (since it's LTS)? - @steveharter
>
> ...
>
> I think we should backport once we're confident in the fix. We may
> want to wait for this change to exist in .NET 8 for a bit before we do
> that. - @davidfowl

I had the same issue, and it was solved for me by updating to version `8.0.0-rc.2.23479.6` of Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (which also requires updating Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions).